# Visual Studio 2015 MVC application template missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 when I want to create MVC application there is no MVC option like below [image]

Also when I open a .cshtml file look like below (not formatting, not coloring, not intellisense)
[image]

I tried below suggestions but doesn't resolve

- Install web developer tools by Visual Studio setup modification
- Change .net framework version from project screen
- devenv.exe /resetuserdata
- Delete %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache files

How can I solve ?

Comment: Try update web tools in visual studio 2015 - I had the same problem.

Comment: Perdido thanks my problem solved. Write your comment as answer I will mark it answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try update web tools in visual studio 2015 - I had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have selected the wrong file editor.

**How to set other editor:**

1. Click with your right mouse button on the View/HTML-page.
2. Click on: *Open with...*
3. Click on *HTML editor* (see image below)

**Set the good editor as default:**

- Click on *Set as Default* (image below)

---

This problem can occur by clicking on an other editor and clicked by *Set as Default*.

[image]